# How to fix Magento2 MySQL error message ERROR 1054: 1054: Unknown column 'entity_id' in 'NEW'

Tags: magento2, database, magento-enterprise

I recently upgraded Magento 2.07 to Magento 2.1 and then to 2.1.1 but now I get the MySQL error `ERROR 1054: 1054: Unknown column 'entity_id' in 'NEW'` any time I try to import a product or update a product attribute.

I can't re-import my DB backup either because MySQL reports errors whilst importing the backup about NEW.entity_id

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution

Just toggle your indexer mode from `schedule` to `realtime` and then back to `schedule`. You can use the Magento Admin (System->Index Management) or the command line tool thus:

```
bin/magento indexer:set-mode realtime
bin/magento indexer:set-mode schedule
```

[As described in the Magento2 documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html).

#### What's occurring?

The error is due to some tables eg `catalog_product_entity_int` having triggers on them so that the scheduled indexer knows what to index. The module CatalogStaging (or one of its dependencies) changes a column name in the table from `entity_id` to `row_id` but the trigger does not get updated so it still refers to `NEW.entity_id` when the `entity_id` column no longer exists.

The triggers are created when the index mode is set to `scheduled` so this situation may affect any DB of a Magento install that has been set to index on schedule *before* upgrading to 2.1.

The fix is simple but not obvious : toggle the indexer to `realtime` (update on save) and then put it back to `schedule`. This clears the triggers and then recreates them with the correct reference to the updated column name: `NEW.row_id` in the trigger as now required by the Magento_CatalogStaging module

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/339814/86901

Answer (score 0):

Suppletion: I ran into this problem, by forgetting to enable maintenance mode on my local work. After enabling the error was gone, by re-running the same commands for setup upgrade