# Magento 2: Error in setup:upgrade in magento 2

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade

I am getting the following error during setup:upgrade:
 **EDIT**

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'entity_id' in 'NEW', query was: CREATE TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_int_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_product_entity_int FOR EACH ROW
```

Can anyone please help me to know how to resolve this error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are u devloping a custom module??

Comment: No, actually I disabled some of the modules of enterprise edition and run setup:upgrade command.

Comment: maybe you have disabled any core module which in used in another module so don't disable core module..

Comment: See https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134667/how-to-fix-magento2-mysql-error-message-error-1054-1054-unknown-column-entity

Answer (score 0):

- Please check the module which throws this error.
- Check its update/upgrade scripts.
- Try to disable a module if it's not necessary.
- Check DB integrity. (the module may expect that the column exists)
- Try to downgrade the module version in `module_setup` table and see
  which version adds the column in the setup script/patch and run
  `setup:upgrade` again

Answer (score 0):

Some modules have a folder called `Setup`. The files in Setup modify the database in some way and are run during `magento setup:upgrade`.

In your case if you have a new installation make sure you have an available database server and that it is accessible. Also check that app/etc/env.php reference that server.

If you had a working installation then check any newly installed modules. You can disable them with `magento module:disable module_name` and then run `magento setup:upgrade` to see if it works better.

You could also search for the error in the code but 'entity_id' and 'NEW' is just too common. If you have more information it would be easier to give an advice.