# Magento 2: 2.4.3 Upgrade error "Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'entity_id' in 'NEW'"

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2.4.3

**I'm getting this error after upgrading from 2.4.1 to 2.4.3p1. I'm running setup:upgrade command it's showing me below error.**

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'entity_id' in 'NEW', query was: CREATE TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_entity_int_after_insert AFTER INSERT ON catalog_product_entity_int FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_attribute_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogrule_product_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalog_product_price_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
INSERT IGNORE INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES (NEW.`entity_id`);
END
```

I tried this solution [How to fix Magento2 MySQL error message ERROR 1054: 1054: Unknown column 'entity_id' in 'NEW'](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134667/how-to-fix-magento2-mysql-error-message-error-1054-1054-unknown-column-entity)

It's the same error as in the upgrade command, check screenshot:-**https://nimb.ws/82nV45**

### Update

It was a mistake from a fellow colleague, I was told to resolve the errors of the upgraded setup. When the second time I tried to upgrade I didn't check the version before upgrading so basically I was trying to upgrade from **2.4.1(Enterprise)** to **2.4.3(community)**

> so Now I have upgraded to **2.4.3(Enterprise)** and the issue wasn't
> seen while running upgrade commands.

**Hope it helps.**

Answer (score 3):

Please try to update the indexer from schedule to real-time & then again back to schedule.

Use these commands -

bin/magento indexer:set-mode realtime

bin/magento indexer:set-mode schedule

Please try and let me know if this work

Thanks,
Rashi

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have tried that as well but it didn't work. Also, I have updated the question. It was a mistake on my side, I was trying to upgrade from 2.4.1(Enterprise) to 2.4.3(community) now it's fixed.

Comment: Oh, then that was obvious. Great

Comment: yeah, but I didn't know that version was enterprise so that's my bad. Thank you for your answer though ;)

Comment: Welcome. Please vote if you find it as feasible solution

Comment: Worked, you saved my day.